# How do I make a call with VoiceResponse? Twilio

Tags: java, twilio

I want to make a call using VoiceResponse for all the info on how the call should work, but I can't seem to find how to generate a URI for the call to use (because it requires phone number, phone number, URI in the Call.creator method)

```
                StringBuilder messageB = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 2; i < input.split(" ").length; i++) {
                    messageB.append(" " + input.split(" ")[i]);
                }

                Say say = new Say.Builder(messageB.toString().replace(" ", "%20")).voice(Say.Voice.POLLY_JUSTIN).build();
                Record recording = new Record.Builder().build();
                Pause pause = new Pause.Builder().length(3).build();
                TwiML response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().say(say).record(recording).pause(pause).build();

                String Url = "http://twimlets.com/message";
                Url = Url + "?Message%5B0%5D=" + messageB.toString();

                Call call = Call.creator(
                        new PhoneNumber("+" + input.split(" ")[1]),
                        new PhoneNumber("+xxxxxxxxxxx"),
                        URI.create(Url))
                        .create();
                System.out.println("Call ID: " + call.getSid());

                System.out.println(Url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't use a `VoiceResponse` at the time you are making an API call to Twilio to start a call.

Instead, you need to set up a web application that can respond to incoming HTTP (webhook) requests from Twilio. When the call connects, Twilio will make a request to the URL you send as part of the request and you can use the `VoiceResponse` at that point to build and return the response you want.

You might find it useful to follow one of our tutorials to better understand this. Here's one on [building a click to call system with Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-java-spring).

Let me know if this helps at all.